# Was the RPL language for the Commodore PET ever used other than by its author?

Tags: programming, commodore-pet

Note that this question is about the programming language RPL for the Commodore PET, *not* the HP language with the same name.  RPL was developed by [Tim Stryker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Stryker) and sold through his company Samurai Software at least as early as 1981, together with some other development and debugging tools.  RPL is a stack oriented language, like Forth, and compiles to byte code.  The manual can be found [here](https://portcommodore.com/dokuwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=larry:comp:flash_attack:fa-rplmaual.pdf).

I only recently learned about this language and like its clever balance between simplicity, speed, and compact code.  However, it does not seem to have been very popular.  The only materials that I can find online (e.g. on archive.org) are either generic reviews of RPL, or articles written by Tim Stryker himself.

So my question: Was RPL for the Commodore PET ever seriously used, other than in projects involving Tim Stryker himself?  I’d be very interested in any references.

Comment: What would be considered a 'serious' usage? He seems to have sold the language and it's safe to assume people bought  and used it. Everything thereafter would be quite up to opinion, wouldn't it? (Beside that, nice find!)

Comment: @Raffzahn Hard to define. :-)  Any commercial use for example. But to be honest, I’d love to hear *any* story about it, also the home tinkering applications.

Comment: Well, then maybe simply drop 'seriously' and ask for any project apart from his own (maybe even remove that) in hope for a flood of use cases. I would love to hear from their experience. May ofc take some time for them to find the question, but that't not unusual for stuff like that.

Comment: I've been looking for more info and the media for a few years now but it seems lost to time. Perhaps someone has it but isn't aware it hasn't been archived or that anyone is interested because they're not involved in the vintage computer community.

I've read the manual and it sounds like a pretty neat language. I'd love to try it out and see it ported to more platforms.

Comment: Bespoke languages like RPL tend to have a very small following.  It is like PICK.  Don't know about home projects but commercially, I doubt anyone would have used it.  I worked for a consultancy staffed by electronic/production/mechanical engineers.  Most of them could just about get by with BASIC.  Even Assembler was magic to them.  They would copy whole chunks of code from magazines without understanding what the code was doing and wonder why it didn't work.  If there weren't many articles on RPL in hobby magazines, the take up would have been minimal.

Comment: Can you clarify how RPL is like Forth?  Forth is a type of TIL (Threaded Interpreted Language), and isn't really a bytecode interpreter.  You might say it is an "address interpreter," since a TIL word (subroutine) is usually just a list of addresses (unless it is a base word implemented in machine language).

Comment: @WayneConrad Thanks for pointing that out. It was mainly about the stack oriented part. I rephrased it a bit. Technically the difference in execution seems even not that big. Plus, using byte code instead of address code saves about 50% of space. :-) Judging by some reviews, RPL ran just a bit faster than Forth, but no doubt there would have been various implementations of Forth around with varying speeds.

Comment: @TimLocke Yes, it's a quite interesting case. Not so much as RPN language or it's functions, but the very fine tuned way it was made to fit the PET ecosystem Editor as well as BASIC cruncher is used without any modification. Such pretty integration is a very rare feature and worthwhile to be remembered.

Comment: @cup Hmm, doesn't sound as if software-'engineering' has changed much - just speed up,  thanks to the internet and especially StackOverflow. Less time between idea and failure :))

Comment: @WimC The slow speed of threaded FORTH is in part due the PET using a 6502 which lacks 16 bit operations and a versatile indirect jump. The additional effort needed for transferring to the next instruction levels the advantage threading has over a byte code interpreter loop

Comment: @WimC Stack is not worse than with many other 8 bit systems. In fact, (ZP),Y is not only a great way to have multiple stacks, but as well to handle elements on the parameter stack in a quite luxurious way as it allows direct access to TOS, NOS and further with short instructions and without moving the base pointer at all.

Comment: @WimC there are many ways to use this. and it all depends on stack element size. With a 16 bit parameter stack gain isn't as great. But with an FP based parameter stack, savings are enormous, as now NOS and NOS can be addressed via the SP and NOS with a copy ofsetted by sizeof(FP), with each element at the same Y-value, thus allowing quite tight loops for basic multi element operations. Fast _and_ address independent.

Comment: @WayneConrad "Forth is a type of TIL". Well, no. That's just one way of implementing a Forth compiler. You don't have to do it that way. From the little I've read of RPL at the users' level, it is pretty similar i.e. RPN stack oriented with a separate return and data stack.